# How to store columns as variables importing csv files

Tags: r

while importing a .csv

```
#importing file 
db <-  read.csv("example.csv", sep = ";", header = TRUE)
```

R recognized that the db has 200 observation of 30 variables but doesn't store them as vectors.
Each time i try to call out a variable display:

> error: object 'variable' not found

Hence I assigned each variable in this way

```
Surname <- db[,1]
Name <- db[,2]
```

But I am quite sure there will be a shortcut.

Am i missing to install a package ?

Thank you

Comment: `list2env(db, envir = .GlobalEnv)`. But why do you want to do this? Do you really, really need 30 variables in the globalenv? I would recommend that you don't try to save 3 keystrokes and write `db$Surname`, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much Rui!! Yeah you are right about db$etc. I actually didn't know that option. Super! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could you something like that

```
sapply(names(db), function(name_i){assign(name_i, db[, name_i])})
```

The code goes through every name of your data and creates an object in your workspace named like the corresponding column.

But I am not recommending doing this because this means you split up your data in many objects. You should rather work with the data as it is, since you can do whatever you want with the vectors while they are part of `db`. Just use `db[, "name_of_column"]` or `db$name_of_column`